# Creating custom header for $http in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

In my controller i want send a request using get method if $http, in that get method i want to send the sessionID in headers. Below am giving the code snippet please check.

```
   this.surveyList = function () {
                //return session;
                return $http.get('http://op.1pt.mobi/V3.0/api/Survey/Surveys', {headers: { 'sessionID': $scope.sessionid}})
                .then(function(response){
                            return response.data;
                        }, function(error){
                            return error;
                        });
            }
```

but this is not working when i send this vale in backend they getting null. 
So how to resolve this.

Comment: may be you have mistake in backend. Have you checked url path seperately ?

Comment: Check your browser's *Network* console and see if the request includes the header and expected value. Also, is the backend set up for CORS? Check your console for any errors

Comment: `this.surveyList` and `$scope.sessionid`. Have you injected `$scope` in your controller or you are referencing it through `this`?

Answer (score 0):

we have a issue where the api is getting called twice from angular , however it works only once when called with the POSTMAN. And here with the custom header passed to the api, the action is called twice. What could be the reason for it?

Answer (score -1):

Try in this way,

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://op.1pt.mobi/V3.0/api/Survey/Surveys', 
  headers: {
             'sessionId': $scope.sessionid
           }

}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs,
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Comment: This is functionally identical. `$http.get()` does the same thing as `$http()` with `method` set to "GET"